# why does not ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor provide finite queue?

Tags: java, concurrency

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` extends `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but with less constructor, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` provide an infinite delayQueue, so that  if I submit too many many task, it may cause jvm OOM, why does not it provide a finite queue and reject policy(reject when can't submit new task)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does not it provide a finite queue and reject policy(reject when can't submit new task)?

You would need to ask the designers, but the fact that they decided not to support this *suggests* that they thought it would not be useful.  (Or at least, not *useful enough* to justify the extra complexity.)

There is another reason.  The implementation of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` depends on the queue returning elements in the correct order.  If you look at the source code, you will see that it uses a custom queue class for this.  There is a comment that says this:

> Using a custom queue (`DelayedWorkQueue`), a variant of unbounded `DelayQueue`. The lack of capacity constraint and the fact that `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` are effectively identical simplifies some execution mechanics (see `delayedExecute`) compared to `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Also, it is clear that the delay queue implementation has to have specific operational properties for the executor to work properly and efficiently.  That is probably why they don't permit you to provide your own queue implementation.

Finally, if you want your application to impose a bound on the delay queue size, you could use `yourPool.getQueue().length()` to check the queue length before scheduling a new task.